# How to find index of controls in flowlayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.

I have `Form1` and `flowlayoutpanel`. I dynamically add `Buttons` to `flowlayoutpanel` and the `buttons` details comes from a `database` `table`.

I want to know the name of the first `button` in the `flowlayoutpanel`.

```
for (i = 0; i < DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

          Button btn = new Button();
          btn.Name = DataTable.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
          btn.Text = DataTable.Rows[i]["PostCode"].ToString();
          flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add(btn);
        }            

       String First_Button_Name = ...........
```

Comment: Isn't that just flowlayoutpanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault()?.Name

Comment: KISS: if (i == 0) First_Button_Name = btn.Name;  A bit too obvious perhaps, do show us what you are going to do with that name.  Given that it isn't that useful.

Comment: MineR: yes it is 100% what I want. please put it as an answer. thank you      flowlayoutpanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault().Name

Comment: Make sure you put the ? before the `.Name` since `FirstOrDefault` can return null

Comment: I don't like layoutpanel because it has limited functionality.  I can do the same using panel(s) and get much more functionality.

Comment: jdweng: can a panel auto arrange controls? I dont think so.

Comment: and data binding to `ListBox` seems better if you just need them on separate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the name of the first button to be added to the FlowLayoutPanel, regardless of how those buttons got there, use:

```
 string firstButtonName = flowlayoutpanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the value you are searching for:

```
DataTable.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString()
```

but make sure you have at least an element before you try to get this value.

Comment: Yes I know, but the DataTable gets cleared and the buttons in flowlayoutpanel changes every time. I want to know the name of the first button in flowlayoutpanel without using index of DataTable. tnx